# How to get variables to pass to javascript math.random

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am just totally clueless how to make this happen. Hoping someone could provide some guidance. I have built a chat system that allows random rolls of dice (for a D&D game). Within the chat div I have a form that allows to select the quantity of dice, as well as the dice type (ie. 4 sides, 6 sided, 10 sided, etc.). It then passes the form input with php into a chat.txt file. I am using ajax to display the chat.txt in the chat div.

So when I originally started I made it function for 1d20 (1 20 sided dice). And used x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1) to make it pick a random number between 1 and 20. Well now I need it to be able to detect the quantity of dice, as well as the amount of sides of the dice(d4, d6, d8). Is there a way to pass the quantity and dice variables into the math.random ? and even better yet, then display each number separately (meaning say you roll 2 d6 and get a 5 and a 3. I would like to have it display the 5 and 3 separately. But that is not totally needed, mostly i need to know how to get different random ranges based on the $quantity and $dice. Or maybe a totally different approach that would work? Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
<div id="pageWrap">

<div id="expander"> Expand</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//on submit
{
    $roll = $_POST['roll'];
    $quantity= $_POST['quantity'];
    $dice = $_POST['dice'];
    $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
    $file = fopen('chat.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($file, "<span>". $nickname . " :</span>" . $roll = str_replace("\n", " ", "    <em> Rolls </em>$quantity $dice <em>for</em> $roll") . "\n");
    fclose($file);
}
?>

<form action="" id="rollBox" name="rollBox" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="roll" id="demo">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10">
    <select name="dice">
        <option value="d4">d4</option>
        <option value="d6">d6</option>
        <option value="d8">d8</option>
        <option value="d10">d10</option>
        <option value="d12">d12</option>
        <option value="d20">d20</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Roll</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#rollBox').submit(function(e) {
var x=document.getElementById("demo")
x.value=Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1);
e.preventDefault();
var obj = $(this), // (*) references the current object/form each time
                        url = obj.attr('action'),
                        method = obj.attr('method'),
                        data = {};
                        obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
                        var obj = $(this),
                            name = obj.attr('name'),
                            value = obj.val();
                        data[name] = value;
                    });
$.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: method,
                        data: data,
                        success: function(response2) {}
                        });
                        return false; 
});
});

</script>
</form>
<p id="name-area"></p>
<div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

<form id="send-message-area">
    <p>Your message: </p>
    <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '200' ></textarea>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: There is no such option, for each dice you have to make separate roll

Comment: Ok, so say I made it roll a differently based on the dice option selected. Could I some how pass the quantity?

Comment: well, as far as i know math.random doesn't take parameters, so a way to do this is to make a loop based on the number of dices and apply the type of each time in each iteration to generate the random, add the result to an array and return the array back to be displayed. 
An example on a sample user input and desired result would be helpful.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid Ok well basically it's a form that asks the user to select the number of dice (allows between 1 and 10) and then a <select> where each option is a different dice with a different amount of sides. So say the user enters 2 and d10. It should then display "User rolls 2 d10 for (insert random numbers for each 10 sided dice (2 numbers between 1 and 10)). Any code examples would be VERY appreciated.

Comment: so the user can choose x number of dices x [1-10] each with different number of faces y (2-10)? and then you want to get x random numbers each between y min and y max e.g I would select 6 dices with different faces d3, d4, d5, d6,d7,d8 and receive random[2,1,5 , 6 , 7 , 8]

Comment: Yes except each dice will be the same amount of sides per roll. Meaning you cannot say 1d8 and 3d10. It could only be one or the other. Everything else you said is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I am definitely trying to write code on my own, however I am still a beginner (clearly) and so when I get stuck on something for a long time I end up posting it here. If you really look back you will see that for the most part, I have only received slight suggestions rather than people writing my code for me. I am indeed trying to learn the basics of both javascript and php, in fact this project is for that exact purpose. Is it not fair that when I get stuck I ask for help on here?

Comment: @Aldentec if the answer gives you what you needed, pls check the green sign to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function takes number of dices and dice type and will return an array filled with random number. However, what you need is loop, javascirpt loop to loop thru the number of dices and get a random value for each dice.

```
 function getRandome (num_dice , dice_type) {
    var result=[];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < num_dice; i++) {
        result[i] = Math.floor((Math.random()*dice_type)+1)
    }    

    return result;
```

}

It's up to you how you want to get the input values, **but here's a FULL ANSWER [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GEKD8/)**

now let's see this example

```
var num_dice = 5;// number of dices
var dice_type = 3;//3 faces
var randomArray = [] ;//will store the random result here as an array
 randomArray  =  getRandome (num_dice , type );
var randomString  = randomeArray.join(",");//convert the array to string adding a comma "," between indexes;  
//assign the string result of random to a text field, div, span etc
$("#demo").val(randomString);//jquery
//OR
document.getElementById("demo").value = randomString;//javascript
```

Comment: Ok awesome that is exactly what I am looking for. Now I just need to figure out how to integrate it into my code.

Comment: glad to help, lemme know if u need anything else :P

Comment: I just have one more question on this. Previously it was sending the random number to the #demo text box. This would then take the text in the demo text box and add it as the $roll php variable. 

With your code, how could I get it back into that demo text box? I see it is saving the random numbers as "result" currently.

Comment: a small suggestion, a good practice is to make ur html elements have the same name/id identifier so u won't get confused. as for your question, you want to display the random result in the #demo text box?if so then use this line document.getElementById("demo").value = "YouValueHERE"; or if u r using jquery then $("#demo").val("YouValueHERE");

Comment: Scratch that, I figured it out I think. Is there anyway I could send it to an text input rather than a div for $("#res").html(randRes.join(","));

Comment: Yes, to the #demo text box, exactly.

Comment: ok i edited my last comment, additionally i will add the details to the answer.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! Seriously, your help is more appreciated than you probably know. Thank you so much kind sir!